# Mongodb sort by result of $indexOfCp

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sorting, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Is there a way to sort in MongoDB by $indexOfCp without adding it as field
Currently that what I'm doing

```js
Food.aggregate([
    { $match: { name: { $regex: search } } },
    { $addFields: { score: { $indexOfCP: ['$name', search] } } },
    { $sort: { score: 1 } }
  ])
```

How can I do that  without $addFields?

Comment: Not possible (we exclude `$project` operator too) What is your use case? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to get food by name (regex search), and sort it by index of mtach, so the order will be more relevant

Comment: i see. Why you don't want do It with $addFields? That's because you insert new field? You can Remove score field with $unset

Comment: @Valijon Yes I know, but I wish I could do it without that (more beautiful code, and maybe a little bit performance improvement)